# Visibly & permanently failing GAE tasks

Tags: google-app-engine

The App Engine taskqueues ensure that tasks are retried if they return a status code outside of 2xx range, which obviously includes stray exceptions. This is fine for occasional failures such as timeouts, but in case of permanent failures - when task cannot complete successfully regardless of how many time it's retried - it causes unnecessary load. Of course one could return 2xx in such case but this would not be registered as an errornous request by GAE and not shown in the 'Errors' table on Admin Console dashboard.

Hence I'm asking: is there a way to fail a task in such fashion that it is:

- not retried (permanent failure)
- visible in the Admin Console as errornous request

Comment: if you log with an error level, it's visible as such, whatever the return code (in my experience it's a lot easier to filter by log error level than by result code!).  oh, but that's logs.  do you mean the list of bad pages bottom right on the overview?  if so, sorry, this won't help.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by 'Errors' table on Admin Console dashboard. Of course logging with `ERROR` level would make it stand out in the logs - but only in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do to make a request show up in the errors tab of the admin console is to log at least one message at level `ERROR` or higher. Simply log said message, then return a 200 status code to ensure your task is not re-enqueued.

If all you want to do is stop retrying after a certain number of retries, you can [configure that](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#Configuring_Retry_Attempts_for_Failed_Tasks).

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a catch 22 here. You want to not retry a task that fails in some particular way. But other than HTTP response codes, how is GAE to know? "Yes, I failed, but that's O.K." or "Yes, I failed, and I forever will" aren't possible to communicate given the [HTTP response codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) available (other than maybe "501 Not Implemented", which means something else). The closest you can gets is a 2xx response, which some failure scenarios will preclude.

There's no facility for examining task stack traces, but if there were, determining that a particular stack trace means that a failure condition is permanent is going to be rather difficult. PhD dissertations might be involved.

I think this one comes down to testing and vigilance.